# RollingFileAppender with file database in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

Instead of using a plain text file, I would like to make log4j to log entries to a file database. At the same time, I would like my logs to behave like a `RollingFileAppender`. So all the log entries of the day will go to a certain file (in whatever database binary format it is) and it will automatically switch to another log file every day.

What is the best way to implement this? Is it to implement a full log4j2 Appender plugin from scratch extending `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender`? 
Is there a simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I would first look at creating a specialized Layout for your target binary format. This will allow you to continue to use RollingFileAppender or RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.

Take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-506 for some ideas. Note that this is trying to do something else, in your case you will be processing the standard Messages used by Log4j, but it should give you a good start.